# Filter/Search NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, nspredicate, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary (PerosnsListSections) and a class names Persons

NSMutableDictionary:

- Keys are letters like "a,b,m ..."
- Values are NSMutableArray
               -> NSMutableArray have objects of class Persons

Persons class:
@property (assign,nonatomic) NSInteger pid;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *name;

Now i have PerosnsListSections displayed in UITableView as shown in the image

[image]

what I want to achieve is when user types in the search bar first i have to filter the section which is the first letter then to filter the names under that section.

Sorry for my bad English (:

Comment: Note that there are several different ways to, in one or two lines, "filter" an array for what you want.  But these are not generally going to be any faster than simply writing out the obvious loop, and in a number of cases they can be considerably slower.  There is no shame in writing out the loop which you understand vs using some mystical function you read about and don't really understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first select the correct array in the dictionary by doing:

```
NSString *firstLetter = [searchString substringWithRange:(NSRange){0,1}];
NSArray *people = PersonsListSection[firstLetter];
```

Then you can filter down on the people by using [`NSPredicates`](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/):

```
NSPredicate *namesBeginningWithKeyword = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name     BEGINSWITH[cd] $letter)"];
NSArray *filteredPeople = [people filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[namesBeginningWithKeyword predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"letter": searchString}]]);
```

The question of how you make that be reflected in the tableview's content is a whole another question though.

1. Typically, you'll want your view controller to be the UISearchBar's delegate and react to change using the `– (void)searchBar:textDidChange:` delegate method.
2. There you could just call your tableview's `- reloadData` method so it tries recompute its content, calling all of its dataSource method like `- numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and so forth.
3. In these methods, in turn, you'll want to check whether some text was entered in the search bar and use the above tips to return the right sections/cells.

Comment: It's better again to use an array instead of a dictionary, so that you can address it's contents in O(1) : NSArray *people= PersonsListSection[firstLetterCharacter-'a'] .

Comment: NSDictionaries [use a hash table](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFCollections/Articles/types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001129-102779-CHDBEIHH) for lookup so the average lookup time is O(1), and the worst case is O(log n) so you don't loose much. Also, using an array would imply pre-allocating as many sub-arrays as there can be different first letters.

Comment: The dictionary still contains 25 arrays, one for every letter, so it wouldn't imply wasting more memory.
Also most likely the hash would be different for every word that start with a different letter, but this isn't said. It's an implementation detail, it may also happen that 25 words with all different letters are put in the same dictionary bucket.

Comment: I'd say it's really unlikely that their hashing function doesn't hold basic uniformity properties, so that close numbers (letters from A to Z) would fall in the same bin. Also, with a dictionary, you only need to allocate those you need, so if you have only one name to store, you could have only one array - that'd work (a miss in a dictionary returns nil, whereas a miss in an array throws an exception). It could also evolve to be used with different alphabets than latin.

Comment: @matehat thats an awesome logic, but I have a question is there a way where to filter PersonsListSection rather than having a new array for result (filteredPeople) ?

Comment: That `filteredPeople` array is just the one used to display the result on screen, where your original array would be the one feeding it, which probably needs to stay consistent in case the user erases the search box content and starts a new search.

Comment: But just in case that's really what you needed, `NSMutableArray` does provide a `-filterUsingPredicate:` method which modifies its content in place, discarding elements that don't match.

Comment: Got it, I have created a local (filteredPeople)  array that loads from the original (PersonsListSection) array. and this local array is the one displayed in the view. and in search am filtering the original array (PersonsListSection) and the result saved in (filteredPeople) then reload the tableview (: